# Extracting chosen key:value pairs from a json output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Beginner here for sure.
I try to get a list of dicts with chosen key-value pairs from a json output but I am stuck for now.

json:

```
d = [{'type': 'pages', 'dates': [{'date': '2021-12-01,2021-12-31', 'items': [{'value': '810', 'value_percent': '42.2', 'title': 'Cat', 'stats_url': 'http://clicky.com/stats/visitors?site_id=100', 'url': 'http://acqui.it/cat'}, {'value': '303', 'value_percent': '15.8', 'title': 'Viag title', 'stats_url': 'http://clicky.com/stats/visitors?site_id=1009', 'url': 'http://acq.it/dfgdf'}]}]}]
```

I tried:

```py
list_new = []

for k in d:
    dict_1 = {}
    dict_1['url'] = k['dates'][0]['items'][0]['url']
    dict_1['ruch'] = k['dates'][0]['items'][0]['value']
    list_new.append(dict_1)

print(list_new)
```

Current output:

```py
[{'url': 'http://acqui.it/cat', 'ruch': '810'}]
```

Expected output:

```py
[{'url': 'http://acqui.it/cat', 'ruch': '810'},
{'url': 'http://acq.it/dfgdf', 'ruch': '303'}]
```

Comment: Your array `d` has only one element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for k in d` iterates through the top level of the JSON, which is a list of length 1. I believe what you're trying to do is:

```py
for k in d[0]["dates"][0]["items"]:
    dict_1 = {}
    dict_1["url"] = k["url"]
    dict_1["ruch"] = k["value"]
    list_new.append(dict_1)
```

Comment: yup, this is it